# How to make two buttons in column?

Tags: html, css, button

How can I make two buttons in a column and center?
I tried with flexbox, but when I add `flex-direction:column` it makes buttons to width 100% 
I need like this 
[image]

HTML

```
<form>
  <button type="button">Regulamin</button>
  <button type="button">Formularz kontaktowy</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Show some code. What did you try?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by specifying the `width` to the button and centering it by `margin: 0 auto`.

```
form button {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Sample snippet to work with:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
form button {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button">Regulamin</button>
  <button type="button">Formularz kontaktowy</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the buttons in an additional DIV and apply these styles:

```
form {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

form div button {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}
```